# Which built in classes in java implements Comparator?

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I'm aware that all wrapper classes, such as String, Integer etc implements Comparable interface. Are there any classes which implements Comparator?

Comment: Yes. Please have a look at source code

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: ["All known implementing classes"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) are some of them.

Comment: .or the javadoc

Comment: You can check the Javadoc of the target class that you're interested in. If it is comparable, then it must implement the `Comparable` interface. However, they don't implement the `Comparator`. `Comparator` is used to compare two objects in a specific order. Some classes may provide different comparators for you to do different comparaison.

Answer (score 2):

A glance at [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) (**All Known Implementing Classes** part) shows that it's implemented by:

- `Collator`
- `RuleBasedCollator`